# Error with Case Statement in Alter Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I cannot get SQL Server to parse my query as I tried to alter a table and add a constraint. like so:

```
ALTER TABLE TaxVal
ADD CONSTRAINT ch_taxVal CHECK (CASE WHEN Col1 IS NOT NULL THEN Col2 = 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

I want to update or set the value of col2 base on the value or condition of col1. 
How do I get this done?
Thank you

Comment: How about a trigger instead of a constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constraints only enforce rules about the data you are trying to add or change, they do not modify data. What you want is most likely a trigger that fires after insert/update and changes Col2 based on Col1. It would probably look something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateCol2
ON TaxVal
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
IF UPDATE(Col1)
BEGIN
    UPDATE TaxVal 
    SET Col2 = CASE WHEN i.Col1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
    FROM TaxVal t
    INNER JOIN inserted i ON t.PrimaryKeyColumn = i.PrimaryKeyColumn
END
```

See the MSDN documentation for [CREATE TRIGGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a calculated column is one potential solution to the issue. You can also set the calculated column to [persisted](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx) for performance reasons.

```
declare @table table (
  [column_01] [nvarchar](128)
  , [column_02] as case
       when [column_01] is null
           then
         0
       else
         1
   end);
insert into @table
        ([column_01])
values      (N'not null'),
        (null);
select [column_01]
   , [column_02]
from   @table;
```